# A pagebox in place of fancybox?

Tags: latex

Since fancybox.sty is not compatible with draftwatermark.sty, is there a pagebox that can be applied to the title page of an article?

Comment: Yes---answer from Peter Grill posted 2011.11.03

Comment: Please post future LaTeX related questions as [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Per [this question on watermark on first page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24111/watermark-on-the-first-page-only) there are various options including:

o [the `eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic).  This does not seem to require `pdflatex` to be run twice.

o `\AtBeginShipoutNext` from [the atbegshi package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi).

o `\SetBgContents` from [the `background` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background)